# java.io.file путь к файлу

Tags: java, android, android-studio, файлы

Недавно начал знакомиться с android studio, прошёл несколько уроков, но я никак не пойму. Вот есть папка res с другими папками в ней, допустим я создам там папку "А", а в ней будет файл "Д.*". Вот как к нему указать путь через "File * - new File();" ?

Comment: Да на уроне res. Вот здесь посмотрите : https://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/assets.php

Answer (score 3):

Никак, к нему невозможно получить доступ.

Нужно ложить файл в специальный каталог - `assets` (`src/main/assets/`). Если его нет - нужно создать.

После этого вы можете полоучить InputStream этого файла, только для чтения.

```
InputStream stream = getAssets().open("filename");
```

После этого если надо вы можете сохранить этот файл в файловую систему - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21730182/1159507

Comment: Немного не то. Я начал изучать jsoup, а там чтобы открыть html файл локальный, то надо прописать такую строку:                                        File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

Comment: У `Jsoup` есть метод `parse` который вместо `File` принимает `InputStream`. Т.е. вам всего навсего нужно заменить input на stream.

Comment: Попробую. А вот насчёт каталога. Это дерево создаётся в папке res, где есть другие папки layout, menu и т.д или же папка assetc должна быть на уровне папки res?

Comment: Внимательно ответ почитайте.